# Code attribution to a post quoting an original source

Tags: licensing, attribution

If I found a post that properly quotes code (gives attribution) from an original source, is it ok if I attribute to that post only, or do I need to give attribution to the original source?

---

For instance: I found this StackExchange answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/4533/92787 :

> [Remove color codes (special characters) with sed](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/3584/remove-color-codes-special-characters-with-sed)
>
> ```
> sed -r "s/\x1B\[([0-9]{1,2}(;[0-9]{1,2})?)?[m|K]//g"
> ```

Which properly links to the original source: http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/3584/remove-color-codes-special-characters-with-sed

Is it ok if in my code I put only this:

```
# sed expression taken from https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/4533/92787
[my code] .... sed -r "s/\x1B\[([0-9]{1,2}(;[0-9]{1,2})?)?[m|K]//g" ... [my code]
```

Comment: What's the reson for not just referencing the original article? I'm saying you are taking the wrong approach, just curious as to your reasons.

Comment: @DavidArno No particular reason. It's not that I don't want to link to the original source, it's that since I find the post first, and sometimes that posts add something beside the original (context, explanation, usage example), plus that post properly links to the original, I just copy paste that posts's link. Idk, it's kind of a two birds, one stone...

Comment: plus sometimes a post combines code from multiple sources. So it's a commodity thing, too, especially when it's about a small sample of code.

Answer (score 0):

Surely the IANAL answer is, it depends upon the licence of the original source, and how that may be adjusted by the licence of the attributing site :-(

If there are multiple attributions, I'd leave your example as is, perhaps adding `which was from multiple sources` allowing anyone to follow the link themselves to find the others.

For your exact example, of course, the simple adjustment is:

```
# sed expression taken from http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/4533/92787
# which obtained it from http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/3584/remove-color-codes-special-characters-with-sed
[my code] .... sed -r "s/\x1B\[([0-9]{1,2}(;[0-9]{1,2})?)?[m|K]//g" ... [my code]
```

And if that's how you found it, it attributes both "sources".